# Get user's value in text file - PHP

Tags: php, regex

## What I want to acheive?

I want to create a function that searches for a specific word in a text file. The word to be searched is defined by the user and must be started with a dollar.

## What I tried

I've searched Google and Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find anything.
So I tried on my own:

```
function findText($userinput, $fileinput){
    $file = $fopen($fileinput, 'r');
    if(preg_match_all('/\$(\w){1,25}/g', $file, $matches_all)){
        if(strpos($matches_all, $userinput, $matches)){
            return $matches;
        }
    }
}
```

But it didn't seem to work?

## Basically

### I want to use it like this

```
print_r(findVariable('myword', 'myfile.txt')); //print_r as it's an array
```

myfile.txt is:

```
$myword = also
$myword = and
$myword = this
Hello this is text to ignore
$op = po
Good day
$myword = none
```

Then it must output

```
Array
(
    [0] => also
    [1] => and
    [2] => this
    [3] => none
)
```

Comment: `$file` inside of your preg_match_all doesn't contain the contents of your file.  `fopen` only returns a file handle that can be used to read a file.

Comment: try to use `file_get_contents` instead of `fopen`

Comment: `$fopen` should be `fopen`. You never check that the file was actually opened. The value returned by `fopen` does not return the contents of the file. You define the function `findText`, but later you use `findVariable` (not the same). `$matches` is never properly defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [preg_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php):

```
$data = file( $fileinput );    
print_r(preg_filter('#\$' . preg_quote($userinput, "#") . '\s*=\s*#', '', $data));
```

**OUTUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => also
    [1] => and
    [2] => this
    [6] => none
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use file_get_contents to collect the text file data

e.g:

```
<?php
$filedata = file_get_contents("myfile.txt");
?>
```

You don't need to use fopen with this

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) on the contents of [`file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).  Beware if the file is very large, though.

```
$matches = preg_grep("/\$" . preg_quote($userinput, "/")
    . "/", file($fileInput));
```